# Coupon code working on checkout/#payment but not working on cart page:Magento2

Tags: magento2, coupon

I'm trying to apply coupon code on Magento2 store.
I have created normal coupon code (without any condition) When I applied it on cart page it not working give me an error "The Coupon code is invalid" But when I go for checkout then apply it so it work there (same coupon code )..

Please look into below images.
[image: not working on cart page]

[image: Working on checkout page]

Please assist me !!

Comment: is that depends on grand total?

Comment: NO, Here you can see image of my rule https://s8.postimg.org/q52ukpd6d/code.png

Comment: have you added any condition into rule?

Comment: No, I just do above screen shot setting, That's it.

Comment: How can i debug it ?

Comment: can you open all tab of rule and share screenshot of whole rule info

Answer (score 1):

Go to below js path :-
`app\design\frontend\Vendor_Name\Theme_Name\Magento_Ui\web\js\lib\core\collection.js`

Line no :- 272 (find below line)
`var hasObsoleteComponents = items().length && !_.intersection(_elems, items()).length;`

Just Replace function items just like below

`var hasObsoleteComponents = items.length && !_.intersection(_elems, items).length;`